# Highcharts with heavy data load crashes IE11

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, internet-explorer-11, react-highcharts

I'm using official Highcharts with React on a page to display different measurements. Everything works fine except for IE11 (go figure), which upon a specific scenario crashes the browser.

On the page the user is able to see measurements for daily, weekly, monthly etc. Each of these tabs then renders Highcharts with data for chosen time.
It works fine even in IE11 until user checks tab Monthly and to view the graph in hourly view (standard view for Monthly is a daily chart bar).

When Monthly -> Hourly view, the call responds with an object with about 700 arrays were the data is picked.
I did a test where I stripped the response for that specific scenario so that it showed only 50 entries = still a bit slow but didn't freeze on me.

I've been looking into this since it pretty much matches my issue as well but no luck:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7725

Also, been trying to figure out how to provide a fiddle for this but the project is quite large which makes it difficult to pick bits and pieces.

So this is basically just a shout out to see if anyone has any other ideas. This works flawlessly in Chrome, Firefox etc.
I think it could be somewhat related to the amount of categories that are being set, just as the Github issue above says. But also, I've tried but no luck (or I did it wrong).
I'll provide the set of options that I have for Highcharts:

```
 const options = {
  chart: {
    marginTop: 40,
    animation: false,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: this.state.resolutionType !== 'allyears',
    reversed: true,
    floating: true,
    padding: 0,
    x: 50,
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    itemDistance: 5,
    symbolRadius: 0,
    symbolPadding: 2,
  },
  series: [{
    type: this.state.graphType,
    showInLegend: false,
    data: this.state.newData,
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' :-'
    }
  },
  {
    type: this.state.graphType,
    name: 'Historical',
    visible: this.state.activeHistoricalData || this.state.activePreviousData,
    showInLegend: false,
    data: this.state.historicalData,
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' :-'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'spline',
    name: this.props.latestConsumptionContent('shortTemperature'),
    visible: this.state.activeTemperature,
    showInLegend: false,
    showEmpty: false,
    data: this.state.newTemp,
    yAxis: 1,
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' .'
    }
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      maxPointWidth: 40,
      connectNulls: true,
      events: {
        click: event => this.handleChartPointClick(event.point.time)
      },
    },
    column: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    line: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    area: {
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        symbol: 'circle'
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories,
    tickInterval: getTickInterval(this.state.resolutionType, this.state.periodTime),
    reversedStacks: true,
      autoRotation: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: ':-',
      align: 'high',
      offset: 0,
      rotation: 0,
      y: -20,
    },
    labels: {
      format: getLabelFormat(this.state.resolutionType, this.state.periodTime),
    }
  },
  {
    title: {
      text: this.props.latestConsumptionContent('shortTemperature'),
      align: 'high',
      offset: 0,
      rotation: 0,
      y: -20,
    },
    showEmpty: false,
    reversed: this.state.reverseTemperatureAxis,
    opposite: true
  }],
  credits: false
};
```

Comment: it is related to the styling prefixes that the IE11 does not understands, not the size of data you can fix it with hardcoding or changing all prefixed with some libraries like `plolyfill`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi wouldn't this hit on the whole chart every time, not only for this specific scenario? Because every other variant the user is able to chose works.

Comment: Please provide a live demo that recreates the issue.